# warning - @author: is an unknown tag

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, author

Can anyone help with this issue?
When I try to generate javadoc, tag @author ignores.
All other tags is fine.

And may by some one can say, how to create tag which will put a new date in javadoc when recompile file? I use Intellij Idea.

(sorry for bad English)

Here console log :

```
    Loading source files for package ua.com.softlab.runtime.compiler.cfm...
Loading source files for package ua.com.softlab.runtime.compiler.resource...
Loading source files for package ua.com.softlab.runtime.compiler...
Loading source files for package ua.com.softlab.runtime.compiler.util...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_17
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\cfm\ClassFileManager.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\cfm\ClassFileManager.java:20: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\CompilerMapper.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\CompilerMapper.java:13: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\ResourceObject.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\ResourceObject.java:14: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\CodeCompiler.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\CodeCompiler.java:9: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\Compiler.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\Compiler.java:16: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\Compiler.CompiledResource.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\RuntimeJavaClassCompiler.html...
C:\Users\alexa_000\IDEA\Runtime class compiler\src\main\java\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\RuntimeJavaClassCompiler.java:19: warning - @author: is an unknown tag.
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\util\Path.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\overview-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\package-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\package-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\package-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\cfm\package-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\cfm\package-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\cfm\package-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\package-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\package-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\resource\package-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\util\package-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\util\package-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\ua\com\softlab\runtime\compiler\util\package-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\constant-values.html...
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\overview-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-1.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-2.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-3.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-4.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-5.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-6.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-7.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-8.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index-files\index-9.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\deprecated-list.html...
Building index for all classes...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\allclasses-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\index.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\overview-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\alexa_000\Desktop\javadoc\help-doc.html...
6 warnings
```

Comment: The issue is closed.

The problem was in the symbol ':' at the end of the tag @ author